# How to calculate years in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in PostgreSQL:

```
table1
date_field_1 DATE
date_field_2 DATE
```

I would like to do the following calculation based on the date fields:

```
select 
extract(YEAR from table1.date_field_1 - table1.date_field_2)*12 AS diff_1
, extract(MONTH from CURRENT_DATE - table1.date_field_2) AS diff_2
from table1
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

For Year

```
date_part('year',age(table1.date_field_1 , table1.date_field_2))
```

For Month

```
date_part('month',age(table1.date_field_1 , table1.date_field_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [DATE_PART](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff) function and Subtraction.

```
select 
    DATE_PART('year', end) - DATE_PART('year', start)
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `AGE` function

```
SELECT AGE(date_field_1, date_field_2) FROM table1;
```